# GWT Async Call Blocking the UI

Tags: gwt, asynccallback

I have a text box where the user can type in characters and a suggestion box opens up. 
I have fired events on the key up event . There is a timer set after which an async call is fired and on success of the async call the suggestion list is loaded. 
The problem is that when I start typing characters the loading symbol of the browser appears and it wont let me type any more characters in my text box till the async calls successfully returns and the suggestions are displayed. 
The point is that if the call is async why does the browser block events on the UI.

Following is the code . The fire event calls the async call and prints the end of fire event message. So the async call does not block.
public void showSuggestions(final String query) {

```
    ArrayList<PCTSuggestion> list;
    System.out.println("Show Suggestions");
    if (query.length() > 0) {
        GWT.log(query);
       list = cacher.getCachedvalues(query);
       //list = new ArrayList<PCTSuggestion>();
       if(list != null) {
            if(!isTabOut() || !isBlurred()) {
                display.showSuggestions(PCTSuggestBox.this, list, true, isAutoSelectEnabled(), suggestionCallback);
            } else {
                display.hideSuggestions();
            }
        } else {

             this.fireEvent(new NewSuggestionEvent(query, limit));    
             System.out.println("End of Fire Event");

        }
        //display.showSuggestions(PCTSuggestBox.this, null, true, isAutoSelectEnabled(), suggestionCallback);
    } else {
        display.hideSuggestions();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you perhaps blocking on the completion of the async call in the event handler? Can you share some of your actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there can be 1000 reasons why it is happening. AsyncCallbacks are not really so async. It only doesn't block UI thread when an actual HTTP requests is send. But constructing request, parsing  response and processing callback body happens in UI thread as usual. Possible culprits:

- crazy amount of data is sent over the network
- some ineffective processing of received data
- ineffective rendering of suggestions
- Using Chrome with devmode (Chrome is extremely slow with devmode)

I will not write down other 996 reason here, because it will be easier for you to actually measure what part of your code is slow.

Comment: I also bet that the main reason is the Development Mode.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid making async calls on every keystroke of an input like a textbox.

What you see in Google search's suggestions-as-you-type is not GWT.

If I wanted to implement suggestions-as-you-type, I would have no idea how to implement it properly in GWT. I would have to write the app in javascript. The suggestions-as-you-type service would be in a separate hidden segregated frame/iframe. The keyup handler would be in communication with that frame. In that way, I feel (not that I am right), the textbox i/o will not clash with the async communications.

Perhaps, you should consider Google javascript closure tools http://code.google.com/closure/.

GWT makes it almost impossible for you to address another GWT application, which would sit on another frame, without going thro a server-based even bus.

You need a coordinating parent frame, so that two or more frames needing to reference, and communicate with, each other have to be children of that parent frame.

However, you can achieve that writing in javascript. Writing in javacript frees you from all the tethers and cuffs of GWT.

You could then, perhaps, wrap that service into a JSNI call, so that you could continue using GWT for layout. The problem I see is, how would you make your textbox visible to the external Javascript called by JSNI? Perhaps, by giving the textbox an ID? But wait a minute, GWT does not want to let you give widget an ID. You can assign it an ensure debugID, but is that workable in production code?

You could use HTML elements in uibinder for your textbox. And uibinder allows you to assign an id to a HTML element. But, then you would have to read the value of the input text box thro the dom. I have never tried mixing GWT/javascript this way, just my thought experiments.

Comment: Totally disagree. Suggest-as-you-type works in GWT perfectly. However, unlike the author, I used standard GWT API for that.

Comment: As suggested by Alexey, use a GWT `SuggestBox`, everything is already done.